# Convert the following: $\frac{-1^{k}(k+1)}{2}(-k-2)$ to $\frac{-1^{k+1}(k+2)}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am teaching myself induction proofs and stepping through the algebra for the sample problems. But I got stuck on this part, can't get rid of $(k+1)$.

Can someone please step me through the process (or provide helpful links)? Thank you in advance.

$$\frac{-1^{k+1}(k+1)}{2}(k+2)$$
    to

$$ \frac{-1^{k+1}(k+2)}{2}$$

**EDIT** sorry, my problem is to convert left formula to the right.

**EDIT 2**
[Problem I am looking at](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/213/inductionsampler.pdf) (first page), and bellow is the how it is shown on the example.

$$\frac{-1^{k}(k+1)}{2}(-k-2)$$

to

$$\frac{-1^{k+1}(k+2)}{2}$$

Comment: As written, that statement is false. Plug in $k = 5$ to see that; the left side is $12$, the right side is $3$.

Comment: Can the left hand side be rewritten to resemble the right?

Comment: @DanielPareja Yes: just delete the $\;k+1\;$ on the left hand. :>)

Comment: Nope. The only values of $k$ for which the claim is true are $k = -1, -2$. I think you have to assume that it's a typo (or a "braino") on the part of the textbook author and move on to the next problem. (As a textbook author myself, I can assure you that such things happen!)

Comment: This statement is false as is. Are you sure the value of k is not somehow restricted or that you copied this correctly?

Comment: @DanielPareja Where on that page are you looking?

Comment: @columbus8myhw [Problem I am looking at](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/213/inductionsampler.pdf) The first page

Comment: @johnHughes you may be right, but my math skills aren't so great for me to assume this.

Comment: @timbuc >_>....

Comment: It's a typo. The author meant $\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}(k+1)(k+2)}2$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw for the last step??? So it can't be simplified more than that right?

Comment: Daniel: your math skills don't have to be great. You can see that for $k = 5$ it's false. And you asked folks here because they have *good* math skills, and several are telling you it's not correct. From this, you can deduce one of many things: your author made a typo, or his/her printer made a typo, or your author doesn't know the math, or... but what you *cannot* do is expect someone to produce a valid proof of a statement that you know to be false!

Comment: @JohnHughes I also forgot to mention that my sight is horrid. So there was the possibility that I could missed something. Regardless, thank you for the help and clarifying my doubt =D. I will make sure to inform the author of this typo.

Answer (score 1):

Surely @columbus is correct in his/her inference: the actual problem should be this:

Show that 
$$
\frac{-1^{k}(k+1)}{2}(-k-2)
$$
is the same as 
$$
\frac{-1^{k+1}(k+1)(k+2)}{2}.
$$

To show this, look at the following sequence of steps:
\begin{align}
\frac{-1^{k+1}(k+1)(k+2)}{2} 
&=\frac{-1^{k}(-1)^1(k+1)(k+2)}{2} \text{, because $a^{b+c} = a^b a^c$}\\
&=\frac{-1^{k}(-1)(k+1)(k+2)}{2} \text{, because $-1^1 = -1$}\\
&=\frac{-1^{k}(k+1)((-1)k+(-1)2)}{2} \text{, by distributive law}\\
&=\frac{-1^{k}(k+1)(-k-2)}{2} \text{, by arithmetic}\\
&=\frac{-1^{k}(k+1)}{2}(-k-2) \text{, by commutativity of multiplication.}\\
\end{align}